# Ngnix reverse proxy - url rewrite to avoid "localhost" from elastic enterprisesearch application

Tags: nginx

In nginx, I mapped /appsearch to point to localhost:3002 where Elastic AppSearch is deployed. When I go to that mapped url http://server/appsearch, I see partial content, the urls within content are pointing to http://server/as http://localhost/ etc.. i.e **without /appsearch prefix**.

When I go to http://**127.0.0.1**:3200, the application redirects to http://**localhost**:3002/ent/select . Looks like they hard-coded "**localhost**"
Can some nginx-config help to translate every resouce within webpage to
http://server/**appsearch**/ ?

Wrong url missing prefix: http://tohulp/as
correct url with prefixbe :  http://tohulp/**appsearch**/as

**Perhaps urls in the document need to be rewritten? How to do that in nginx config?** The application is not opensource, so I can't change the code,any solution must be in nginx confing

```
    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  TOHQLP;
        location /appsearch/ {
            rewrite /appsearch(.*) /$1 break;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3002/;      
            proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
    
        }
```

=====
App redirects 127.0.0.1 to local host
[image]

====
The URL rewrite results in the Elastic - Enterprise Search app, not rendering correctly -- perhaps various urls in the document need to be rewritten? How to do that in nginx config?

[image]

==== content source at http://tohulp/appsearch/as ====

Note that the content has localhost:3200, this won't fetch the resources. How can I bypass/prevent/solve this problem thorugh ngnix config?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Seems you are using Enterprise Search, and if you are accessing from external host you need to configure that with `ent_search.external_url`

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/enterprise-search/current/configuration.html

```
# Define the exposed URL at which users will reach Enterprise Search.
# Defaults to localhost:3002 for testing purposes.
# Most cases will use one of:
#
# * An IP: http://255.255.255.255
# * A FQDN: http://example.com
# * Shortname defined via /etc/hosts: http://ent-search.search
#
#ent_search.external_url: http://localhost:3002
```